# Do while wont loop with boolean test C#

Tags: c#, loops, boolean, try-catch, do-while

My do while loop will not loop when bool correctInput gets changed to false. It is supposed to loop until the input is correctly entered from the use. Acceptable inputs are integers greater than zero. Anything that is an integer will throw the try catch and change correctInput boolean to false causing a loop. If the integer is not greater than zero than correctInput will be turned to false causing a loop. Only when the user enters correct input, the loop should exit. It currently is not looping when the input is incorrect.

```
  private static void InputMangementShapeSquare()
    {
        bool correctInput = true;
        int Length = 0;
        string rawInput;
        do
        {
            correctInput = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Length: ");
            rawInput = Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                Length = Int32.Parse(rawInput);
                if (Length > 0)
                {
                    correctInput = false;    //Changes correctInput to false if input is less than zero
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                correctInput = false; //Changes correctInput flag to false when rawinput failed to be converted to integer.
                Console.WriteLine("input must be an interger greater than zero.");                    
            }

        } while (correctInput == false);

        Square square = new Square(Length);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, you want correctInput to be set to false if Length is **less than** zero, but your code sets it to `false` if it is **greater than** zero.

```
            if (Length > 0)
            {
                correctInput = false;    //Changes correctInput to false if input is less than zero
            }
```

It should be:

```
            if (Length <= 0)
            {
                correctInput = false;    //Changes correctInput to false if input is less than zero
            }
```

Comment: just saw that... :/

Answer (score 2):

i would change the `if`:

```
if (Length <= 0) { 
    correctInput = false; //Changes correctInput to false if input is less than zero 
}
```

in **C#**, you could also use `TryParse`, so you do not need the `try catch`:

```
int value;
if (!int.TryParse(rawInput, out value)) {
    correctInput = false;
}
```

And the same with your code:

```
correctInput = false;
do { 
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Length: ");
    rawInput = Console.ReadLine(); 

    int value;
    if (int.TryParse(rawInput, out value) && value >= 0) {
        correctInput = true;
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("input must be an interger greater than zero."); 
    }
 } while (!correctInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment in this block, you have the wrong operator in the if block:

```
    if (Length > 0)
    {
            correctInput = false;    //Changes correctInput to false if input is less than zero
    }
```

If you want to change `correctInput` to false if input is less than 0 then it needs to be

```
if (Length < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the problem in this part of your loop?

```
if (Length > 0)
{
    correctInput = false;    //Changes correctInput to false if input is less than zero
}
```

Shouldn't that read like this instead?

```
if (Length < 0) 
{
    correctInput = false; 
}
```